# ZNE for mitigating errors in probability distribution results

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience, error-mitigation, qiskit-runtime

Can ZNE be applied to mitigate errors for getting the probability distribution in the computational basis rather than mitigating errors for calculation of expectation values?